# SVGs disappear in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg

I've inherited a Wordpress site that uses a lot of SVGs. I made some edits in the dashboard to some of the text and when I looked at the live site, the SVGs disappeared! It looks like WordPress is changing the SVG code (removing the square brackets?). Any suggestions how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out WordPress adds additional code that breaks the SVGs.

```
// <![CDATA   --svg code-- ]] > //
```

IF the above code surrounding the SVG code is removed, the SVGs display again.

Comment: Yup, adding a `CDATA` section would do it :|